# My thinkpad is being throttled to 400mhz per core. Is there any way I can force it to clock to normal speeds with the kernel?

Tags: kernel, cpu, intel, thinkpad, system-programming

there seems to be a common issue with Lenovo ThinkPad and the Intel CPUs being throttled to 400mhz per core:

- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-L-R-and-SL-series/L380-stuck-on-0-4-GHz-when-loading/td-p/4333148
- https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/96gnur/yoga_370_cpu_stuck_at_038_ghz/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/6uhu31/t470_cpu_throttling_stuck_on_400_mhz_when_on/

The interesting thing is that this is not merely on an operating system basis. Even in BIOS or Diagnostics, this throttling occurs. It sometimes returns to normal speeds, but not forever. The battery is also not charging when it's under throttled.

There does not seem to be a clear answer as to what causes this and as to what is the solution. The catalyst for me seems to when I let the laptop discharge while in sleep. I have been dealing with this issue for a week.
I have already:

- Updated the BIOS
- Rollbacked the BIOS
- Tried different chargers
- Unplugged the battery and drained the capacitors
- Unplugged the clock battery
- Changing the CPU settings in BIOS
- Pressed and hold down the reset

And pretty much everything short of getting a new battery, and playing with the kernel. As far as I understand, people have tried getting a new battery, and that solution only works some of the time.

I'd like to see what I can do with the kernel; I am fine programming in C++, Qt, and C, but I just don't know my way around the kernel or have any experience working with CPUs and the like.

1. Is there a kernel module I can explore to deal with this?
2. Can the kernel force higher clock speeds to even begin with?
3. Are there perhaps more streamlined existing solutions that will force my computer to go back to regular clock speeds?

Thanks.

---

Edit:
After changing the governor from Powersave to Performance, I am still seeing the same issue:

Before:

```
➜  ~ cpupower -c all frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

---

After:

```
➜  ~ sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance       
[sudo] password for anon: 
Setting cpu: 0
Setting cpu: 1
Setting cpu: 2
Setting cpu: 3
➜  ~ cpupower -c all frequency-info            
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but last time I looked into this my solution was to control the processor's "P-states" and "C-states".  Hopefully that is something searchable for you.  There are linux commands to do this.

Comment: you may want to check on the cpufreq scaling governors in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy?/scaling_governor.  It should be performance instead of powersave

Comment: @JustKhaithang It unfortunately is choosing the lowest range.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4ZJ8WTvYDs/  One thing I am wondering about is this: `current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware`  `current CPU frequency: 400 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)` It lists it twice and I am uncertain what to make of it.

Comment: try disabling thermald. There's apparently a bug in thermald version < 2.4 . You can read more here. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/fedora-33-cpufreq-stuck-at-400mhz/10085/5

Comment: @JustKhaithang I tried it, and no cigar. This makes sense because the throlling occurs not only in linux, but in BIOS and UEFI Diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

- Shut the laptop off completely

  - Windows 10/11 you need to press shift while selecting shutdown
  - on Linux, you probably already have this disabled
- Press the power button for 10 seconds while off. (The laptop should spin up the fans but not display anything on screen. After around 10 seconds the fans will spin down.)
- Turn on the laptop normally, USB-C PD charging should be back to normal and the CPU should not be throttled.

I had some issues with my Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro with an AMD Ryzen 7 5800H also getting pegged to 400 Mhz, which started happening after a BIOS update, but surprisingly only when connected to USB-C PD chargers. This laptop has a dedicated external power brick too, and plugging in that one didn't lead to the system slowdown I was seeing.

This was happening on Linux, Windows and in the BIOS settings, so the operating system couldn't be the culprit. In the end, using the solution from this [thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/findpost/1516/5065696/5256121) solved my issue, pressing the power button for 10 seconds while the laptop was off most likely clears something in the CMOS and brings the laptop back to normal.